# How to make the same file included in two different files living in different directories to redirect on the same final path?

Tags: php, html, directory, subdirectory

I have a `logout.php` file that is located in the root directory and it goes like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['logout'])){
    session_destroy();
    header('location: ../index.php');
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <button name="logout" class="logout">Logout</button>
</form>
```

This button is included inside the `header.php` and the `header.php` is what actually causes the problem, which problem goes like this:

There are two header files which live inside two different directories, one in the root folder and the other one in a sub-folder `/users/` and if you have seen the code you may already assume that the logout button executes it's function properly each time you are located in the `/users/` directory eg. `localhost/rootdirectory/users/dashboard.php` but each time you visit the root folder and try to logout from there it redirects you one directory up, leading you right on the WAMP's index page (in my case).

Now you must wonder why would i use two different headers so here is an explanation to it:

The content inside the `header.php` is exactly the same in both of the files but i have a duplicate of it because i found it as the only solution to the same type of problem that i had when i was creating the `header.php` or more precisely right after i created the sub-folder `/users/` and tried to include the `/rootfolder/header.php` inside the `/rootfolder/users/index.php`.

What happened here is similar to what is happening now with my logout button and the main reason of why am I asking this question is because i can not create duplicates each time i run into this type of problem.

When i tried to include the `/rootfolder/header.php` inside the `/rootfolder/users/index.php` i lost connection to every file linked inside the header including the `style.css`

Right now we are located at `/rootfolder/users/index.php`

```
<?php
    include '../header.php';
    include '../footer.php';
?>
```

and this is how `/rootfolder/header.php` looks like

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //we link the connection file
    include "pagesetup/config.php";
    //we populate the database with tables and default data
    include "pagesetup/createtables.php";
    //we store the page title inside of a variable
    $get_title = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT title FROM pageinfo");
    while($row = $get_title->fetch_assoc()){
        $page_title = $row['title'];
    }    
    //we unset the login and register sessions which are used to display the outcome
    //of the login/register attempt
    unset($_SESSION['login']);
    unset($_SESSION['register']);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
        <title>
            <?php echo $page_title;?>
        </title>
    </head...
```

In this situation my index page looks like this and i have no access to any other file linked inside it (including the most important `config.php`)
[image]

And the only way for the `style.css` file to be applied to `/rootfolder/users/index.php` was to copy the `header.php` inside `/rootfolder/users/` and then change it's paths like this

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //log in protection
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
        header('location:../index.php');
    }
    //we link the connection file
    include "../pagesetup/config.php";
    //we populate the database with tables and default data
    include "../pagesetup/createtables.php";
    //we store the page title inside of a variable
    $get_title = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT title FROM pageinfo");
    while($row = $get_title->fetch_assoc()){
        $page_title = $row['title'];
    }    
    //we unset the login and register sessions which are used to display the outcome
    //of the login/register attempt
    unset($_SESSION['login']);
    unset($_SESSION['register']);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/javascript.js"></script>
        <title>
            <?php echo $page_title;?>
        </title>
    </head...
```

and then of course change the path in the `/rootfolder/users/index.php` too

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';
    include '../footer.php';
?>
```

This question may be a little bit off topic but i couldn't find the right way to ask it so if you understand my problem and have something that would help me learn to work with directories i would be more than happy to hear it.

**Peace!**

Comment: You need to `exit()` after your header directive. Otherwise the rest of your code is still executed!

Comment: Relative URLs are interpreted by the client, not the server. It doesn't know anything about the include files on the server, it just interprets it relative to the URL that it's currently displaying. If you're using the same `header()` line from different URLs, the simplest solution is to make it an absolute URL instead of relative.

Comment: @Barmar This method works and also makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify this:
Check to see if a session exists, delete it if it does, then redirect to another page.

```
<?php
   session_start();
   session_destroy();
   exit(header("Location: ../index.php"));
?>
```

Save this as a seperate script, "logout.php", and instead of using a button, just link to it `<a href="logout.php">logout</a>` from any/all of the appropriate pages. Unless you are really committed to having a button...

---

Appended:

1. Do the pages have the correct action in the form?
   The code you show
   for your `logout.php` file includes `<form method="POST">`: there is
   no `action="logout.php"` to send you to that (seperate) file. The
   rest of the code you show is the `<head></head>` area (of both
   pages) which does not show the HTML of your button form.
2. Both pages should send the user to the (same, seperate) `logoff.php`
   file.
   Based on your question, you have the output of `logoff.php`
   going to 2 different locations. If you send both to the same file,
   then you need only be concerned that your `logoff.php` script has the correct path to the `Location: ../index`. If `index.php` and `logoff.php` are in
   the same level directory, then the correct redirected path would be:
   `Location: index.php`.

In summary, if your site visitor clicks on logoff (button or link), they should be sent to the seperate `logoff.php` script. That script in turn "redirects" (or sends) them to the `index.php` page.  
Because these two pages are in different directories, you will have to use a different path to send the user to the `logoff.php` script. Example:

- The link for `localhost/rootdirectory/users/dashboard.php` is one
  directory above root, the link should be `../logout.php`.
- The link at the root level shoule be `logout.php`.
- The redirect link inside `logout.php` remains constant as
  `index.php`.

Comment: This is how my page is already set up, you never understood the problem. It is about where the logout.php script is located and the difference between the redirecting the browser to `../index.php` or just `index.php` depending on from which location you are approaching the logout function

Comment: No, in my case the script is in a separate file named `logout.php` which is located in the root folder of the project (same where `index.php` lives) and is included in `localhost/rootfolder/users/header.php` like this `include '../logout.php'` and in `localhost/rootfolder/header.php` like this  `include 'logout.php'` . However i got some explanation in the comments section on my question which helped me to solve the problem but i appreciate you trying to help me and hope that this gets you a better image of how is my code formatted

Comment: Your answer is based on your opinion that the logout script is written inside the header which is not. The form is inside a separate file named `logout.php` and since there is no action defined the form it submitting to itself check this out http://prntscr.com/m6plii but since you are engaged with my problem and you are trying to solve it i would be glad to approve your answer as the right one if you provide a proper solution no matter how many edits it takes

Comment: just to clarify... the session is already started inside the `header.php` and since `logout.php` is included inside the header there is no need for `session_start()` inside `logout.php`. some further info: http://prntscr.com/m6pnt6

Comment: Your comments contradict each other. You stated that `logout.php` is a seperate file. You also stated that `logout.php` is included inside the header. My solution is to remove logout.php from the header(s) entirely and use only the seperate logout.php file.

Comment: Included like this `<?php include "logout.php"; ?>` if i remove this line of code from my header how would the button will be displayed anywhere on the page?

Comment: So the separate file `logout.php` is included inside the header, which makes both of my statements true

Comment: Put the `<form action="../logout.php" method="POST"><button name="logout" class="logout">Logout</button></form>` in the page. Adjust the action href depending on what page the form is on (relative to the location of the `logout.php` file, or use the absolute url if that's easier for you). The `logout.php` file should have php code only (no `<form>`).

Comment: Okay so, i am not troubling this problem anymore, i have solved it 2 days ago with the absolute url but anyway the way that you are proposing is not a proper solution and is not making any difference no matter if i have the entire code inside `logout.php` or html separated from php and out of curiosity why should `logout.php` contain only php and no html and how would it make any difference?

Comment: Concept: Code once and link. That way if you need to change something, you only need to change it in one file, not in every header in multiple directories. This is simply a matter of efficiency. I'm sorry that you are having so many issues understanding how it will benefit you in the end.

Comment: I believe that i have only one logout script with a single code in it that code can be changed within the script only, yet affect every place where it is included. Separating the HTML from the PHP wouldn't make any difference. Other than that i believe that you are having hard time trying to prove yourself worthier by saying things that are not making any sense or i am just dumb(blind) enough not to see how your proposal is different and benefits more than the way i am using (i even find my way shorther as it is consisted of 1 line of code in each header instead of an entire form per header).

Comment: I am just trying to be honest, no hard feelings. Peace! ✌️

Comment: I think this really comes down to a language barrier. Good luck to you.